# Android Imageview ontop of each other with rotation

Tags: java, android

This is my situation.  I have a one imageview that's being place as the background and a second imageview that's being placed on top of it.  In the imageview that's being used as the background it rotates so I would like the imageview ontop of it to follow the rotation translation that is done.  How would I do that? Essentially what I want is to anchor the second imageview to follow when the other imageview is being rotated. This is the code I have so far:

```
          <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/unit"
                        android:src="@drawable/unit"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:src="@drawable/button"
                       />
                   />

    private void rotate(int rotation) {
    button.setTranslationX(1);
    button.setTranslationY(-1);
    if(rotation  > 35) {
        rotation = 35;
    }
    if(rotation  < 0) {
        rotation = 0;
    }
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    unit.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    matrix.postRotate(rotation, 
    unit.getDrawable().getBounds().width(),     unit.getDrawable().getBounds().height());
    unit.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rotate the Relative Layout instead?

Comment: I don't want to rotate the image on top of the other image because of how the image will like, it will also be rotated.  I only need the translation to be on top of it with the same alignment.